# AFNetworking Swift Integration

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I know there are other similar questions and I have seen some of them to try fix my problem. It would be great if anyone could help me on that.

I am trying to integrate AFNetworking on a iOS Project using swift. I am using cocoapods to manage external dependencies. My pod file is like this:

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 platform :ios, '7.0'

 pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2'
 pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

And then I have a Bridge-Header.h to be able to use Objective C. It works with the FacebookSdk, so I added here the import for AFNetworking.h:

```
#ifndef MyProject_Bridge_Header_h
#define MyProject_Bridge_Header_h

#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

#endif
```

After that when I try something like:

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
```

It is not recognized.

I have been following these links and everything seems ok to me:

https://medium.com/@aommiez/afnetwork-integrate-swfit-80514b545b40
https://medium.com/@stigi/swift-cocoapods-da09d8ba6dd2

Any idea of what the problem can be.

Thank you a lot

Comment: Try Alamofire instead. It's a Swift-based networking layer. More up to date. It's also on github.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnnaDickinson for your help! It seems a good library, created by the same as AFNetworking. I will give it a try.

Comment: Working on that again I successfully put it working. Not sure what was the problem but I have re done the process and main difference I think was the file name changed to MyProjectName-Bridge-Header.h instead of only Bridge-Header.h. 

Also changed the content of this simply to:
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

Comment: Fun fact, AF actually stands for Alamofire.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a new project in xcode.
2. Then goto terminal ->your project directory-> type pod init
3. Then goto terminal ->your project directory-> type pod init
   this will install pod into your project.
4. Then close existing xcode project and goto project location and you will see there is file called pod ,then add this pod ‘AFNetworking’, ’~> 3.0 inside that pod file and save it.
5. Then goto terminal again and in your project directory type pod install and enter.
6. Then goto project folder and you could see there is a workspace file named with your project.
7. Open it in xcode.
8. Goto Add new file and then in source section add a header file.Name it as YourProjectName-Bridging-Header .
   9.Then in project settings section, goto Swift Compiler -Code Genaration
   And add your header file name to Objective -C Bridging Header.
   9.Important thing is you need to give exact location of your file.

[image: Image of a sample project hierarchy]

- In my case my Networking.Bridging-Header.h is inside Networking -> Networking->Networking.Bridging-Header.h.
- So I need to add Networking/Networking-Bridging-Header.h from starting the group that my bridging header is in.
  -Thats’ it.Then inside any swift file you could simply use your pod .NO need to import any thing.That is the beauty of bridging.